# Need help for finding a generator

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

$I=\{a+bi \in R\mid a \equiv b\pmod 2\}$ is an ideal of $R=\mathbb Z[i]=\{a+bi\mid a,b \in \mathbb Z\}$. Can somebody help me to find the generator of $I$?

Comment: You should have noticed that in $\Bbb{Z}$ one of the smallest numbers in an ideal generates it. This is natural, because in that ring products tend to be bigger than the factors. The same holds ring $R$, so try a small element of $I$.

Comment: And welcome to Math.SE! We seek to help you help yourself. To that end it is often necessary that you include your own thoughts on the problem. Otherwise it is difficult to give helpful advice.

Answer (score 1):

**Claim**: $I = \langle 1 + i \rangle$.

**Proof**: Notice that $1 + i \in I$ as $1 \equiv 1 \pmod 2$ which means $\langle 1 + i \rangle \subseteq I$.

For the reverse containment, let $a + bi \in I$, and $a, b \in \mathbb Z$ with $a \equiv b \mod 2$. Since $\mathbb Z[i]$ is a Euclidean Domain, we can use the division algorithm and so there exist $r, q \in \mathbb Z[i]$ with $r = c + di$, $q = e + fi$ such that $$a + bi = (1 + i)q + r$$ where $c^2 + d^2 = N(r) < N(1 + i) = 2$ or $r = 0$. Notice that $$(1 + i)q = (1 + i)(e + fi) = e + fi + ei - f = (e - f) + (e + f)i$$ and so $e - f \equiv e + f \pmod 2$ since $-f \equiv f \pmod 2$. Since $r = c + di = (a + bi) - (1 - i)q$ and since $a \equiv b \pmod 2$ and $e - f \equiv e + f \pmod 2$, then $$c = a + e - f \equiv b + e + f = d \pmod 2.$$
For $c^2 + d^2 < N(1 + i) = 2$ we must have $c = d = 0$ and hence $r = 0$. Conclude that $a + bi = (1 + i)q$ and so $a + bi \in \langle 1 + i \rangle$ which means $I \subseteq \langle 1 + i \rangle$.

Conclude $I = \langle 1 + i \rangle$.